# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Can't enable hibernate statistics

Hi.
I'm currently looking for ways to optimize my database persistence.
I'm using JPA Hibernate in my SpringBoot service and I want to check if my queries are using batch processing.

To check that, I need to enable the hibernate statistics logs.
I have already added these two in my application.properties:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug

But it seems that my application disregards these settings.

Do you have any idea why the statistics do not show?

Thank you.

Comment: May be your logging framework is eating all the logs in case the log level incorrectly set.

Comment: Hi @kedar. I'm using sl4j and using log level info

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final and this enabled the statistics for me:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener" level="INFO"/>
```

Example output in my log file:

```
2020-02-13 17:27:57,188 [main]  INFO (o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener:258 end) - Session Metrics {
    700 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    2500 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    678100 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    939200 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

Comment: Hi, I am having this issue too. Using spring boot 2.3.0,  and spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true. Other sql config works such as spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true. Also added to logger: <logger name="org.hibernate.stat" level="debug"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener" level="INFO"/> . ANy ideas?

Comment: with Spring Boot (2.3.1) you can use something like
logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener=INFO
in your app properties file to have stats logged

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issues.

Try to check your logging config file which may block this output.
Simple way is to disable your logging config file like rename it.

For my case, I renamed logback-srping.xml to a-logback-spring.xml. And after restarting my service. It works.

[image]

Hope this can help.